# Usage for Subversion different than source code

Tags: svn, version-control, versioning

I've worked with SVN in college projects and in my actual job. The main usage is to keep versions for the source code files in the project: make changes on trunk, create branches to play or make any kind of work with the source code files and define the final versions using the tag folder; this is a good software tool and people in my work (including myself) is very attached with it. But lately, I've seen in my workplace that there are similar problems handling documents (word, excel, some power point and other assets).

I know this could be a silly question but it would be good to use SVN to handle versions for these files too? Maybe (or maybe not) SVN will behave the same handling these kind of files as with source code files, but I just have this doubt in my mind. I've used it to save documents before on a college project and it didn't give problems, but after doing some research on the internet I haven't found any post saying that you could use SVN for a different purpose than keeping versions of source code. This question is just to make sure I'm not a crazy guy or alone in this type of crusade.

Comment: It works fine, there are limitations on merging binary files + it's probably not as efficient, but it does work quite well with word documents for example, where merges can be treated like different revisions through track-changes.

Comment: For an example check out polarion.com: it is a (commercial) tool for requirements management and it uses SVN as its base. I heard they are changing to GIT though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SVN doesn't care what the contents of your files are; I have repositories which consist of nothing but MS Office docs & PDFs. You can't perform merges or diffs on binary files, but SVN will happily version them without trouble.

Just make sure you set `svn:needs-lock` on your binaries to help avoid conflicts - you can't resolve conflicts easily like you can with plain text.

Setting your mime-types appropriately (`svn:mime-type`) is also helpful.